Swift: how to build property in Base class in library
I need to build a base class in library, however the library doesn't have the knowledge of this property. In such situation how can I property build the base class.
here is the code example:
///Code in the library
open class BaseClass {
    // the problem is here. how I can set up such a property in the base class 
    // where the type of the property is not available in the base class.
    public var property: ThePropertyTypeThatThatLibraryDonotKnow 

    init(property: ThePropertyTypeThatThatLibraryDonotKnow)
}

///CodeIn the main app
class ThePropertyTypeThatThatLibraryDonotKnow {
     var someProperty: Int
}

///Usage of the BaseClass

/// 1 use the BaseClass directly
let property = ThePropertyTypeThatThatLibraryDonotKnow()
let object = BaseClass(property: property)

/// 2 subclass the BaseClass.
class SubClass: BaseClass {}
let property = ThePropertyTypeThatThatLibraryDonotKnow()
let object = SubClass(property: property)

So is there a way that I can declare the property the base class.

How about declaring a protocol that represents ThePropertyTypeThatThatLibraryDonotKnow with some constraints as get set properties?

You cannot alter stored properties of the class, so you need to rethink your strategy. This is an XY problem though, since you clearly trying to achieve something by adding that property to existing class. So what is it? explain your use case.

I think I grasp what you're asking. Could a generic class provide the flexibility you need? Can you elaborate on the problem?

There are several ways you can approach this, but the approach I'd probably take is to make your base class generic.
open class BaseClass<T> {
    public var prop: T

    public init(prop: T) {
        self.prop = prop
    }
}

In your app you can create a specialized subclass of your generic base class:
struct InternalType {
    let value: Int
}

final class SubClass: BaseClass<InternalType> {}
let instance = SubClass(prop: InternalType(value: 99))
print(instance.prop) //prints InternalType(value:99)
print(instance.prop.value) //prints 99

In order to make the generic type more useful within your subclasses, you might want to define a protocol and constrain the generic type to it.
//Library
public protocol HasIntValue {
    var value: Int { get }
}

//Updated definition of BaseClass
open class BaseClass<T: HasIntValue> { ... }

//App
extension InternalType: HasIntValue {}
extension SubClass {
    func add(other: T) -> Int {
        return prop.value + other.value
    }
}

I recommend reading up on Swift's generic types. The Swift Programming Language is a good place to start: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/generics/#Generic-Types
